# How to know the maximum pull up/down resistor of a specific logic pin of an IC?

Tags: resistors, pullup, pulldown

I am designing a circuit and needs to place some pull downs on the address pins of [PCA9546](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9546a.pdf) and usually my go to resistor values for these kind of situations is either 10k ohms or 100k ohms. These values work almost all the time.

Having said that, I thought that if I were designing this circuit where power consumption is critical surely the datasheet must have some information that tells me the maximum pull - up / down. But I could not find such information on the datasheet.

What section of the datasheet does information belong? If the IC that I have given does not have this information (considering its not meant for low-power applications) can you give an example datasheet that has this information?

Comment: the datasheet states that the current will be \$1 \mu\$A max if address pins are tied to Vcc or to Gnd

Comment: Does the address need to be changeable? 0R strap resistors would work in this case too. Or omit the resistor and just connect to VCC or GND. Only if the address needs to be dynamically set via switch or IO pin it might need pull-downs or pull-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the maximum leakage current into these pins:

[image]

You need to choose the pull-up resistor value small enough that the leakage current flowing through it doesn't push the pin input voltage out of the valid range for the logic level you're trying to pull to.

Since \$1\ \mu A \times 10\ k\Omega\$ is only 1 mV, your default choice is fine.

Comment: but what would be the formula for finding the highest value can go? You used ohms law, V= IR, but what would be the target voltage so that R will be the only one left? or looking at it in a different way, the current must be higher than 1uA,  R < V/I , R < 3.3v/1uA , R < 3.3M ohms is it correct that that is the highest value?

Comment: @Jakequin A voltage drop of 3.3 V over the resistor would be able to change a 0 signal to 1. The voltage must be small enough to be harmless. (Look at V_IL and V_IH.)

Comment: @CL. apologies im still having trouble to understand. How do I calculate this _"small enough to be harmless"_, what is harmless and what is not, where can i find that in the datasheet? V_IL  = 0.99v and V_IH = 3.8 (MAX) how do i use these values?

Comment: @Jakequin If your actual low-level signal has, for example, 0.1 V, then you can afford at most 0.89 V until you reach V_IL.

Comment: @CL. alright i can understand that. Where does the resistance play in what you have said?

Comment: @Jakequin You have to compute how much voltage is dropped over the resistor; this is the error offset voltage that the leakage current can introduce.

Comment: @CL. I think i get it now so i have to make sure that the voltage drop does not exceed the V_IL (0.99), A 1M resistor in this would not work since  v = (1uA)(1M); v = 1volt. which is greater. Follow up question, this is independent of the supply voltage be it 5v or 3.3v the process is the same? also does this works for both pull ups and pull downs? Does seting your value close to the max V_IL okay for example 0.9v ( 900K ohm)

Comment: The leakage current is specified as "± µA", so it can flow into or out of the pin. And if the original signal is not exactly at 0 V, you have less headroom.

Comment: @CL. thank you very much good sir i understand now, If you want to post what we have discussed as an answer i would gladly accept it. although Photon have basically the same answer but it lacks the key concepts that i was lacking